# is there a way to add pygame.display.update to an indented loop

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a simple game on pygame I am using this code to implement a jump yet the update function does not work inside of the for loop is there a way to resolve this:

```
while Running:
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        if Y > 0:
            if Jump == False:
                for i in range(1,100):
                    pygame.time.delay(10)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    Y -= 10
                    Jump = True


    if not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        if Y < 500-Height:
            Y+= Vel
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (X, Y, Width, Height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

the the jump does work yet the animation does not it just cuts to i = 100 instead of a smooth transition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use nested loops to implement the game process. You've a game loop, use it. All you need is the main game loop and an event loop. When the <kbd>UP</kbd> is pressed, then set the state `Jump`. Reset the state when the jump has ended. Calculate the position of player dependent on the state `Jump` in every frame. e.g.:

```py
jump_i = 0
while Running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        if Y > 0 and Jump == False:
            Jump = True
            jump_i = 0

    if Jump and jump_i < 100:
        jump_i += 1
        Y -= 10
    else:
        Jump = False

        if Y < 500-Height:
            Y += Vel

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (X, Y, Width, Height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: yes I added that to the code my question is if I can update it inside the for loop of K_UP or does it only be called on that specific spot

Comment: Thanks! it really helped